# obtener id de un ítem seleccionado en un JComboBox en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo  un método que carga las delegaciones en un `JComboBox`, pero necesito obtener el id de la delegación seleccionada para poder enviarlo al otro método que se llama `cargarColonia` y de esta manera cargar en el otro `JComboBox` las colonias relacionadas con la delegación.

He tratado de cargar en un vector los registros del `ResultSet`, pero no tengo idea de como pasar el id del ítem seleccionado al otro método.

```
public void cargarDelegacion() {
        cboDelegacion.removeAllItems();
        String[] registros = new String[2];
        try {
            st = cn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select iddelegacion, delegacion from delegacion");
            while (rs.next()) {
                registros[0] = rs.getString("iddelegacion");
                registros[1] = rs.getString("delegacion");
                cboDelegacion.addItem(registros[1]);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    public void cargarColonia(int id) {
        cboColonia.removeAllItems();
        try {
            st = cn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select idcolonia, colonia from colonia where iddelegacion =" + id);
            while (rs.next()) {
                cboColonia.addItem(rs.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder hacer eso lo primero seria declarar una variable de tipo entero donde se almacenara el id del valor seleccionado del combobox.
Después de eso debemos de ir a los eventos del combobox y seleccionar el siguiente evento "ItemStateChanged".
ItemStateChanged es un evento que detecta cuando el valor de un jcombobox cambia.
Para hacer uso de esto se debe de programar de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cmbAgenciaItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        if (cmbAgencia.getItemCount() > 0) {
            confCatalogos catSel = (confCatalogos) cmbAgencia.getSelectedItem();
            this.idAgencia = catSel.getId();
            System.out.println(idAgencia);
        }
        cmbMarca.removeAllItems();
    }
}
```

El evento hacer referencia al valor del jcombobox.
Se llama primero a evt.getStateChange() que detecta si el id del jcombobox cambio y igual el estado al id seleccionado.
Después revisa que la propiedad de getItemCount que cuenta la posición del valor en jcombobox sea mayor a 0.
confCatalogo hace referencia a la forma en la que llevamos el control del jcombobox.
Después de hacer esto igualamos la variable tipo entero en este caso "idAgencia" al valor contenido dentro del jcombobox.
Y para comprobar que el id a cambiado llamamos System.out.println(idAgencia).

Answer (score 0):

Mira castea el primer resultado de rs.getString("iddelegacion");  y manda a llamar el método cargarColonia en cargarDelegación

```
public void cargarDelegacion() {
    cboDelegacion.removeAllItems();
    String[] registros = new String[2];

    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select iddelegacion, delegacion from delegacion");
        while (rs.next()) {
            registros[0] = rs.getInt("iddelegacion");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("delegacion");
         } 
         cboDelegacion = new JComboBox(registros);
         cbDelegacion.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 String contenido = cbDelegacion.getSelectedValue();
                 int  id = Integer.parseInt(contenido[0]); // castea de String a int
                 cargarColonia(id); // manda a llamar el método cargar Colonia
             }
         });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

public void cargarColonia(int id) {
    cboColonia.removeAllItems();
    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select idcolonia, colonia from colonia where iddelegacion =" + id);
        while (rs.next()) {
            cboColonia.addItem(rs.getString(2)); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: es lo que ya hice pero carga nada los registros asociados al ultimo id que recupera del jComboBox delegación

Comment: prueba con el evento del jcombo